# How to automate Excel file transfer from Sharepoint online to GCP Cloud Storage?

Tags: excel, google-cloud-storage, sharepoint-online, file-transfer

I am a newbie to GCP. Need advice and guidance on how to automate Excel file transfer from Sharepoint online to GCP Cloud Storage. Not manual upload to GCP Cloud Storage.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar post about this problem in the Power Automate community,but it is currently not solved or got some direct reference,and I have not found any ready-made resources on GitHub.This is the post: [Connecting Power Automate to Google Cloud Platform Resources](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Connecting-Power-Automate-to-Google-Cloud-Platform-Resources/td-p/1501678)

I'm more usually used to getting files from SharePoint Online to my personal Google Drive via Power Automate.
This is the flow template for reference:[SharePoint Online files to Google Drive Files](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/13267289fb064f24988d69c629f1c125/sharepoint-online-files-to-google-drive-files/)